# Jmeter Remote Start : Error during JRMP connection establishment;

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to connect to a Slave from the Jmeter MAster, however when I click on `RUN > Start Remote > select the Remote machine` i get the following error :

> Error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Prior to this as I do not need a secure connection I edited the USER PROPERTY file in the Jmeter bin directory with the following statement :

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

I also started the Jmeter-server bat file,

then restarted Jmeter for it to take effect, but no joy.